# A replacement for std::find_if and std::bind2nd on a sorted vector

Tags: c++

I have a date class `GregorianDate`, and a `std::vector<GregorianDate>` instance `dates`. That vector is sorted.

Currently, given a `GregorianDate` instance `date`, I have the expression

```
std::vector<GregorianDate>::const_iterator it = std::find_if(
    dates.begin(),
    dates.end(),
    std::bind2nd(std::greater<GregorianDate>(), date)
);
```

I'm keen to replace this with

```
std::vector<GregorianDate>::const_iterator it = 
    std::lower_bound(dates.begin(), dates.end(), date);
```

since `bind2nd` is deprecated and `dates` is sorted.

Are the results of the two expressions identical for any `date`?

Comment: You *could* keep using `std::find_if` but change `std::bind2nd` to a lambda expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results are not the same.  `std::lower_bound` gives you the first element in the set that is greater than or equal to the element you are looking for, or last if none are.  `std::find_if` on the other hand will only return the element that the comparator returns true on and `std::greater` wont return true if the elements are equal.

You would need to use `std::upper_bound` to match your call to `find_if` (`upper_bound` returns the first element greater than the element you are looking for), or change your comparator in `find_if` to match how `lower_bound` works.

Comment: So the result is exactly the same for any date if I use std::upper_bound(dates.begin(), dates.end(), date);?

Comment: @SasidiranSangamanautram Yes.  `upper_bound` exactly matches what your call to `find_if` does.

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Let's get you that T-shirt, mug, and pen by Easter!

Comment: @Bathsheba I wish.  I'm at least 4 days out.  Thanks though